# OAuth Error: verification of signature failed

Tags: php, javascript, ios, oauth

I have my Oauth Provider which is written in php using the library [Oauth php](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/)

and I am making a phonegap application to use Oauth service from my server using jsOauth library [link](https://github.com/bytespider/jsOAuth)
I am following the steps provided in [this tutorial](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt5p1)

But I am getting error from server while requesting the access_token in exchange with the request token received.

> OAuth Verification Failed: Verification of signature failed (signature base string was "GET&http%3A%2F%2Fapi.amishra.abc-dev.com%2Foauth%2Faccess_token.php&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.cd.com%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dab17b706d7320aa3607c8a774954eb495f7cccb3338a1f44ad4396c5a9ff69db%26oauth_nonce%3D5B702F7E46305E3B%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1343032505%26oauth_token%3D1ca90d9a8039ebe04e1c25eec852137b0500d0c4f%26oauth_version%3D1.0").

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are not sending the `oauth_verifier` parameter that you should have received in the authorization step. I.e when your callback was invoked after the user authorizes your application. This applies to the latest OAuth 1.0a specification, in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-2.2.

Also, there is no need to send `oauth_callback` parameter on the access token request, that is needed only in the request token step.

Comment: yes I am not sending oauth_verifier parameter as I am not getting any. After callback I am only getting oauth_token   http://www.cd.com/?oauth_token=82af5125009056578897fb97bf796e0b0500d13ef

Comment: Alright, what remains for you to do is to check what signature base string you are using when creating your signature and compare it to the error message's.

Comment: the signature base string is same as error. and this is the method I am using to create the signature "if (function_exists('hash_hmac'))
  {
   $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", $base_string, $key, true));
  }"